# C pretty printer based on S-expression and Visitor pattern

Tags: java, c, eclipse, code-generation, pretty-print

I have a program that generates an S-expression of a program that I would like to turn into automatically generated C code.  Currently I have a hacked up implementation partially working, however small details such as instantiating temporary variables and handling function parameters (with said temporaries) is proving to be frustrating.

The internal representation is a tree structure (in Java/Eclipse), so at present I use the Visitor pattern to walk the tree and generate my code.  My question is twofold: first, is there an easy approach for generating C code based on an S-expression (or an AST object in memory) .  If not, is there a well-described algorithm for generating C code that I could follow to generate the code?  I'd prefer to simply call an external tool or drop something into Eclipse, as my currently hacked solution is proving frustrating to finalize.

Comment: I think what you might be looking for is a Lisp compiler.

Comment: Good suggestion.  I'm going to give [ECL](http://www.cliki.net/ECL) a try and see how it goes.

Comment: I should mention that the nodes have custom labels in my S-expression.  Can a Lisp compiler still generate code based on that?